# Is there anyway make python's error message stop disrupting the flow

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I execute the code below, is there anyway to keep python compiler running the code without error messages popping up?

Since I don't know how to differentiate integers and strings,
when `int(result)` executes and `result` contains letters, it spits out an error message that stops the program.

Is there anyway around this?

Here is my code:

```
result = input('Type in your number,type y when finished.\n')
int(result)
if isinstance(result,str):
    print('finished')
```

Comment: Please provide an [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: There's the `try...except...` and there's the `.isdigit()` check for checking if a str is a valid integer

Comment: You shouldn't fight the language. Consider what the return value of invalid operations should be. `None`? Should this `None` then propagate through everything it touches? If you really want stuff like this, I suppose you could look into a functional programming language which makes it easier to pass through "invalid" results (e.g. using `Maybe` monad). Doing this in python sounds like a pain.

Comment: Python is a strongly type language and knows the difference between numbers and letters very well. Except of cause numbers are presented as strings. And BTW Python is not a compiled language. It generates bytecode but is interpreted at runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's look at your code:

```
int(result)
```

All that will do is raise an exception if `result` cannot be converted to an `int`.  It does **not** change `result`.  Why not? Because in python string (and int) objects cannot be changed, they are *immutable*.  So:

```
if isinstance(result,str):
    print('finished')
```

this test is pointless, because `result` will *always* be a `str` because you have not changed it - that's the type returned by `input()`.

The way to deal with error messages is to fix or handle them.  There are two general approaches, "look before you leap" and "exception handling".  In "look before you leap" you would check to see if `result` can be turned into an `int` by using a string test like `str.isdigit()`.  In python the usual way is to use exception handling,  for example:

```
result = input('Type in your number,type y when finished.\n')

try:
    # convert result to an int - not sure if this is what you want
    result = int(result)
except ValueError:
    print("result is not an int")

if isinstance(result, int):
    print("result is an int")
```

You can see I specifically tested for `ValueError`.  If you don't have this and just have `except` then it would trap *any* error, which could mask other issues.

Comment: This is a great answer! I hope the OP considers this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, with Python and many other languages, you can differentiate types.

When you execute `int(result)`, the `int` builtin assumes the parameter value is able to be turned into an integer. If not, say the string is `abc123`, it can not turn that string into an integer and will raise an exception.

An easy way around this is to check first with one of the many builtins `isdigit()`, before we evaluate `int(result)`.

```
# We assume result is always a string, and therefore always has the method `.isdigit`
if result.isdigit():
    int(result)
else:
    # Choose what happens if it is not of the correct type. Remove this statement if nothing.
    pass
```

Note that `.isdigit()` will only work on whole numbers, `10.4` will be seen as *not* an integer. However `10` will be.

I recommend this approach over `try` and `except` clauses, however that is a valid solution too.

Comment: *why* do you recommend this approach? Generally, in Python, [the opposite is considered more typical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360858/what-is-the-eafp-principle-in-python)

Comment: What do you think `int(result)` on its own does?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Whilst the opposite is typical, as cdarke says in the comment below, a bare except is dangerous for numerous reasons. However I do not expect newcomers to Python to fully understand the exception model. Hence, why I recommend users don't use them until they have learnt what it actually does to prevent programming errors in the future. Should I include this in my answer?

Comment: @cdarke `int(result)` is in place because since the switch from Python 2 to Python 3, there were a few changes, one such change was to change `input()` to no longer automatically evaluate the input type, and instead return a string result. So it is necessary to first convert `result` into an integer before the OP can presumably interact with `result` as an integer (say adding or subtracting it). Though I do understand that `int(result)` doesn't actually change the `result` variable, only evaluates it, I just didn't take it upon me to answer that too, I only wanted to solve the question at hand

Comment: My point was that you posted code that did not "work".  Surely we have a responsibility to point out glaring mistakes?  Your point about python 2 use of `input()` is valid, it had not occurred to me that the OP might have been reading an old book or web posting.

Comment: @cdarke That's a very good point, I guess I was just trying to do one thing at a time, but as you say it is good practice to make sure I cover all errors :)

Answer (score -2):

You can put everything that might throw an error, in a try block, and have an except block that keeps the flow of the program.

btw I think, in your code it should be, `isinstance(result,int)` not `isinstance(result,str)`

In your case,

```
result = input('Type in your number,type y when finished.\n')
try:
    result = int(result)
except:
    pass
if isinstance(result,int):
    print('finished')
```

Comment: Did you actually try this code?  For a start the `continue` is invalid outside a loop.  Second, a bare `except` is dangerous and should not be generally used.  Third:  `int(result)` **does not change result**, `result` will stay a string and it will never print "finished".

Comment: @cdarke my bad, edited. Can you explain why is a bare except dangerous?

Comment: A bare `except` is dangerous because it will trap *any* error which can mask a genuine error.  For example, if you mis-typed `int(result)` as `int(ressult)` then you should get a `NameError`, but with a bare `except` it will ignore this typo and carry on.